# Internal (unseen) damage from a 40ft climbing fall

Tags: climbing, health, injury

I am aware that the statistics regarding a 40ft climbing fall, which result in "decking-out" are not favorable. I survived such a fall only recently. Major injuries seem to have only been a broken & fractured right leg (above and below the knee). This being said, I am sure that there is a lot more unseen/non-diagnosed damage to my body, including a concussion.

I will be going for more tests, these will not necessarily be related to my bone breakages, to hopefully find out what other damage occurred.

Does anyone have the knowledge or experience to help me start my own self-diagnosis?

Comment: Why not ask an actual doctor?

Comment: As it states above, I am going for more tests. Unfortunately, during my recent visits to hospital their only main concerns were breakages to my bones and not soft tissue, ligament or tendon damage.

Comment: I edited your question to take out the reference to self-diagnosis.  If we helped you with a self-diagnosis, we would be clearly giving you medical advice, which we don't do as a matter of principle.  The last sentence, as edited, is, I think, on the right side of the line.  Best wishes for a complete recovery.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about personal health recommendations.

Comment: That's a nasty fall.  Glad to hear that you pulled through!

Comment: @imsodin the question is asking for potential health issues, much like all of the questions tagged [tag:health] these are in scope, like [the one you answered here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/8766/4079)

Comment: @JamesJenkins There is a very clear distinction: In the linked question someone not affected by a problem that is acute in the outdoors is asking about what he should do, if he should ever become affected by it in the outdoors. This is asking from the perspective of somebody who is currently affected by a health issue and what he should do, to improve the diagnosis. Yes, you can probably alter this question far enough, that it will be something generic, but it still started as a personal health recommendation and that is way too dangerous to let it be.

Comment: We cannot possibly tell you how to start your own self-diagnosis.  We are not MDs, and it would be dangerous for you to take medical advice from strangers. We can tell you to go to a doctor ASAP if you suspect a concussion, or if, e.g., you have been vomiting non-stop for days, but this is only common sense.  If you want suggestions on how to manage your interactions with your doc, then an edit, since revoked, changed your question to ask for that.  You can bring back that edit if you want, or ask that it be brought back.

Comment: In case you don't know how to rollback, go here https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/posts/20523/revisions and then click the rollback link as illustrated in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vqsn.png

Comment: @Simonw I just wanted to let you know, so you don't get discouraged by this site, that there has been a conversation on the side going on about your question. Whether it is on topic seems debatable, but an even bigger concern people have is about you getting dangerous self-diagnosis answers. Sue, for example, made a big deal about your health and being terrified that someone would cause you to do something dangerous (she cares a lot and is very concerned about everyone, including you).

Comment: @Simonw If what I said in my previous comment seems hypocritical since we have answered other health questions, keep in mind that those other questions generally revolve around "I'm hurt and I can't get medical help soon. What can I do?", and in those situations you have to do _something_. As a loophole, you could pose similar questions that way in the future, "If I'm still where I fell and cannot leave the area, what injuries should I be worried about?" Though that would get different answers, related to what you could treat, so not perfect in this case.

Comment: @Simonw And lastly, concerning your actual situation, I would suggest you get a second opinion from another doctor, especially from a different medical facility, if that is possible. People who are concerned their doctor is missing something and who eventually find out they were right tend to go to multiple doctors for the issue, sometimes many doctors for rare diseases that doctors don't like to diagnose. I wouldn't suggest "many doctors" for you, but at least a second opinion might put you at ease.

Comment: Doctors are more concerned with life or limb. If you're going to live then they're satisfied. Physiotherapists/Athletic therapists are the ones you need to go see about recovering from soft tissue damage or other sports injuries.

Comment: Am I the only one who, based on the title, thought that the question would be about damage to **the rope**?

Answer (score 5):

A mostly non-medical answer.

If you live in the United States (US) and you have health insurance.  You can be relatively sure that the medical and legal communities both agree there there is very little risk of significant medical issues requiring more testing, then you are recieving.

Google 'medical testing based on malpractice concerns' and you will find millions of articles talking about the number of tests doctors order to prevent getting sued.

Trauma perspective.

I used to be [EMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_medical_technician) with a volunteer fire company that had, what has been listed as one of the 10 most dangerous roads in the US, I have seen a lot of trauma.  There are no absolutes, but in general, the bad things might happen, have fairly observable symptoms.

Could you have had some strange physical stress, the has weakened some blood vessel, that could rupture at any moment causing you to die from internal bleeding in minutes; yes, you could.  But realistically [those type of bleeds (aneurysm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aneurysm) happen from organic issues (life > death) much more commonly.  Otherwise healthy people die from these all of the time.

I would not be overly concerned with self diagnosis, focus on the what the medical staff are telling you, things like blood clots following a lower leg fracture are big risks. Don't let worry about the very low probably, overlooked risks distract you from addressing the very high probability risks of recovering from your diagnosed injuries.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm having trouble parsing "But realistically those type of bleeds happen from organic issues (life > death) much more commonly. Otherwise healthy people die from these all of the time.", could you reword? I know this answer is on hold/closed but so long as we're here anyways...

Comment: @Adonalsium I added the word 'aneurysm' and a link. Locations vary (brain, heart, liver, kidney), but this is one of the most common causes of death in "healthy" people.

Comment: It was more of the "happen from organic issues (life > death)" that seemed hard to penetrate for me.

Comment: @Adonalsium not sure how to clarify that.  I am using organic as synonym of natural occurrence.  Everything that lives, ultimately dies. I would probably be getting out of scope if I went much further than that.

Comment: Oh. You meant "naturally occurs". 100% makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

Doctors are not omniscient.  They miss things.  Some are sedentary, and they don't understand how important a full recovery is to an athletic person.

Everyone, when going to a doc, needs to think through what to ask his doc, and know how to ask -- or insist -- effectively.  We are not giving the OP medical advice here; we are suggesting how to manage his visits to his docs effectively.

I suggest:

(1) **if you suspect concussion, drop everything and go to a doc, an ER or a walk-in clinic sooner than ASAP.**

(2) When you visit your docs, bring someone with you who knows your situation well, is outspoken without being abrasive, and can advocate for you.  Such a person is called a Patient Advocate and, according to the [Institute for Health Care Improvement](https://www.npsf.org/page/patientadvocate) can be a professional PA or a family member or close friend.  The Institute says:

> A time of illness is a stressful time for patients as well as for
>   their families. The best-laid plans can go awry, judgment is impaired,
>   and, put simply, you are not at your best when you are sick. Patients
>   need someone who can look out for their best interests and help
>   navigate the confusing healthcare system–in other words, an
>   advocate.....
>
> An advocate is a “supporter, believer, sponsor, promoter, campaigner,
>   backer, or spokesperson.”......  An effective advocate is someone you
>   trust who is willing to act on your behalf as well as someone who can
>   work well with other members of your healthcare team such as your
>   doctors and nurses.
>
> An advocate may be a member of your family, such as a spouse, a child,
>   another family member, or a close friend. Another type of advocate is
>   a professional advocate. Hospitals usually have professionals who play
>   this role called Patient Representatives or Patient Advocates.

Comment: For any of the immediate measure to be taken in case of a concussion it is way too late. You may not agree, but having such discussion about health issues is exactly why this question is a bad idea. Doctors most definitely are not gods and it is definitely a good idea to think for yourself. It is also definitely a bad idea to let strangers on the internet think for you. The advocate sounds like a really good idea and a good thing to recommend, it's just not really what was asked (showing again, that you need to go against the question for it to be a more or less responsible answer).

Comment: @imsodin Sure, instant measures are better, late measures are worse, and even later measures are even more worse.  As for "going against the question", the OP had 18 hours to roll back my edit.  Silence is assent.